# equivalent to windows xcopy on php?

Tags: php, exec, xcopy

I'm converting an old system from windows batch files to php to run on a debian box. I've encountered some curly xcopy commands and wonder what the equivalent code for them would be in php.

```
xcopy src dest /Q /R /S /Y /exclude:c:\exclusions.txt

xcopy src dest /C /I /Q /R /S /U /Y /exclude:c:\exclusions.txt
```

http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html helpfully tells me what the switches are:

```
/C = continue if error
/I = assume destination is a folder
/Q = quiet (no output)
/R = overwrite read only files
/S = copy folders and subfolders recursively
/U = copy only files that exist in the destination
/Y = supress prompt to overwrite destination file (and assume YES)
```

`c:\exclusions.txt` just has file names to skip

```
.ds_store
thumbs.db
.git
.ssh
.htaccess
README.MD
```

The switches that I'm mostly wondering about are `/U`, `/R` and `/S` - how to recursively copy a folder structure only copying matching files that exist in the destination structure.

I imagine I'll have to use exec() from php, but not sure what I should be running. Any pointers appreciated :)

Comment: See the [`cp`(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) man page, or `tar`/`pax` and `rsync` for more feature-creep.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, different project, same problem and found my own question again! Here's what I did this time (where cp/rsync not always available) :

```
// php xcopy, assumes /s /q /c /y /r switches
// /exclude switch via skipfiles and skipfolders (appended to in-built defaults)
// /u switch via $ifindest
public static function xcopy($source, $dest, $skipfiles = [], $skipfolders = [], $ifindest = false) {

    // ensure source and destination end in one directory separator
    $source = rtrim($source,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $dest = rtrim($dest,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    // normalise skip arrays and apply defaults
    $skipfolders = array_unique(array_merge(['.git','.ssh','editor'], array_map('rtrim', $skipfolders, array_fill(0, count($skipfolders), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))));
    $skipfiles = array_unique(array_merge(['.ds_store','.htaccess','thumbs.db','about.txt','readme.md'], array_map('strtolower', $skipfiles)));

    // examine folders and files using an iterator to avoid exposing functional recursion
    foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
        $name = strtolower($iterator->getFilename());
        $path = $iterator->getSubPathName();
        $folders = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, empty($iterator->getSubPath()) ? $iterator->getSubPathName() : $iterator->getSubPath()); // subpath is empty at source root folder
        $skip = count(array_intersect($folders,$skipfolders))>0;

        // skip this iteration due to a folder match?
        if ($skip) continue;

        // skip this iteration due to a file match?
        if ($item->isFile() && in_array($name, $skipfiles)) continue;

        if ($item->isDir()) {
            if (!file_exists("{$dest}{$path}")) {

                // create destination folder structure
                mkdir($dest.$path,0775,true);
            }
        } else {
            if ($ifindest) {
                if (!file_exists("{$dest}{$path}")) continue; // copy only if file exists in destination already
            }

            // finally we can copy the file
            copy($path,$dest.$path);
        }
    }
}
```

There's a few notable holes here, particularly in that there's no exception handling, but it got me out of trouble this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just  to give you a hint for the right direction I would start with the [Symfony command line component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

You could then code the switches to -q or --quiet instead of /Q and then build out the logic with php's [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) functions.

Having said all this unless you really want the fun exercise in php coding it would probably be better to use a bash script or similar and use the cp command.

Comment: yeah, even though the rest of the framework is in php, there's no reason to use it when a decent command line option exec can do the same in this case. Thanks for the Symfony pointer :)